# trying to grab image url within div's children

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm making an extension that grabs an image URL within the "uCW" div on an HTML page.

Currently, I have:

```
var uCW = jNode.closest("div._q7o");
var image = uCW[0].children[1].getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src;
console.log(image);
```

That finds the image by going into the div/children and pulling the image. Unfortunately, this method is problematic, since it stops working if the children change, which they regularly do.

Instead, I want to select the image by searching the div and all its children (there are a lot of them) for the first image/string that starts with "https://external" (all the images I want start this way, and that doesn't seem to change.)
This is what I tried:

```
var uCW = jNode.closest("div._q7o");
var image = $(uCW).find([name^="https://external"]).src;
console.log(image);
```

This doesn't work. The console just prints "undefined."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this, if `ucw` is a classname (if it's an id, you would write `$("#ucw")` instead):

```js
var image = $(".ucw").find('[src^="https://external"]').attr("src");
console.log(image);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ucw">
   <img src="https://external/1.jpg"/>
</div>
```

If your images have a name attribute with the source of the image as value, you can also adjust your attempt to fetch the images via their name attribute like you did:

```
 var image = $(".ucw").find('[name^="https://external"]').attr("src");
```

Comment: Hm still getting undefined. uCW is actually a variable I gave to a div with a classname _q7o, does that change things?

Earlier in my code, I have var uCW = jNode.closest("div._q7o");

Comment: @codi6 In this case, it should be ucw.find('[src^="https://external"]').attr("src"); or $(ucw).find('[src^="https://external"]').attr("src"); (works both).

Comment: That worked! Just had to change to $(uCW).find('[src^="https://external"]').attr("src");

Thank you so much, I've been trying to do this for days.

Comment: @codi6 Glad that I was able to help :)

Comment: Btw, for extra credit ... I'm trying to do the same thing with a different link, but I'm getting undefined. Can't figure out why this would be any different. var url = $(uCW).find('[src^="https://l.facebook"]').attr("src");

Comment: @codi6 If the src of this image starts with I.facebook it should work. Do you have an example for such an image? Have you tried a big I as well as a small L for l.facebook?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212731/discussion-between-codi6-and-matthias-h).